# PAPI for MIC installed, components correctly discovered, but PAPI_add_event fails

Tags: intel, performancecounter, xeon-phi, papi

I compiled and installed the latest PAPI 5.4.0.0 for MIC. My configure options are:

```
CC=icc CXX=icpc ./configure --with-mic --host=x86_64-k1om-linux --with-arch=k1om --with-ffsll --with-walltimer=cycle --with-tls=__thread --with-virtualtimer=clock_thread_cputime_id
```

The problem is PAPI_add_event always fails, both in my own program and in the test program. The reported error is "Invalid argument". Any idea why? I tried to re-configure and re-install, but the problem remains.

```
[root@mic2 bin]# ./papi_cost
Cost of execution for PAPI start/stop, read and accum.
This test takes a while. Please be patient...
cost.c                                       FAILED
Line # 231
Error in PAPI_add_event: Invalid argument
```

These are the results shown by 'api_component_avail'. It look pretty normal to me. It also matches with this thread: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/530598

```
[root@mic2 bin]# ./papi_component_avail
Available components and hardware information.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PAPI Version             : 5.4.0.0
 Vendor string and code   : GenuineIntel (1)
 Model string and code    : 0b/01 (1)
 CPU Revision             : 3.000000
 CPUID Info               : Family: 11  Model: 1  Stepping: 3
 CPU Max Megahertz        : 1052
 CPU Min Megahertz        : 842
 Hdw Threads per core     : 4
 Cores per Socket         : 60
 Sockets                  : 1
 CPUs per Node            : 240
 Total CPUs               : 240
 Running in a VM          : no
 Number Hardware Counters : 2
 Max Multiplex Counters   : 128
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Compiled-in components:
 Name:   perf_event              Linux perf_event CPU counters
 Name:   perf_event_uncore       Linux perf_event CPU uncore and northbridge
   \-> Disabled: No uncore PMUs or events found

 Active components:
 Name:   perf_event              Linux perf_event CPU counters
                                 Native: 140, Preset: 14, Counters: 2
                                 PMU's supported: perf, knc, perf_raw


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 component.c                             PASSED
```

Answer (score 0):

I lower the version of PAPI from the latest 5.4.0 to the previous 5.3.2 and the problem is gone. Thus I believe this is a bug of this current version.